# Multiple parameters in MySQL "IN" query

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm clearly doing something wrong in the parameterization, but not sure what the proper syntax is.

**Desired, but doesn't work: multiple conditions in where IN**

```
data = ['lol', 'hi']
query = """ select word, count(1) from table where word in (%(ids)s) group by 1"""
pandas.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=db_engine, params={'ids':data})
```

*Output:*

```
InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)') [SQL: "select word, count(1) from table where word in (%(ids)s) group by 1 "] [parameters: {'ids': ('lol', 'hi')}]
```

**Not desired, but works: single condition in where IN**
(it's fine with a list of length 1)

```
data = ['lol']
query = """ select word, count(1) from table where word in (%(ids)s) group by 1"""
pandas.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=db_engine, params={'ids':data})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets around the placeholder. As it is the query is comparing `word` against `(('lol', 'hi'))` after parameter substitution done by pymysql, or in other words a scalar against a tuple. A list of length 1 is fine because the result is `(('hi'))` and SQL actually treats the scalar `word` as a 1-column row when comparing, which the perhaps slightly non obvious error hints at.

So the query should look like:

```
query = """
    select word, count(1)
    from table
    where word in %(ids)s
    group by 1
    """
```

Comment: To clarify, you mean to remove the parentheses (not brackets) around the text in `query`, correct?